# Add CSS class(es) to WooCommerce cart items with (or based on) product categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I am trying to add the WooCommerce product class to the cart items on the cart page.

I have products in a specific category with faster shipping (quickship) and want to highlight them on the cart page to make my customers aware of it before check out.

I've tried to add the

```php
wc_product_cat_class( '', $category );
```

and the

```php
wc_product_class( '', $product );
```

in the cart.php template file. Neither really did what I hoped for. Any suggestions or options for other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to overwrite/modify template files. You can use the `woocommerce_cart_item_class` hook and [has_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/)

The table row (`<tr>`) will contain an extra class, based on the product category

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_item_class( $string, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    // Specific categories: the term name/term_id/slug. Several could be added, separated by a comma
    $categories_1 = array( 63, 15, 'categorie-1' );
    $categories_2 = array( 'categorie-2' );
    
    // Has term (product category)
    if ( has_term( $categories_1, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        $string = 'my-class';
    } elseif ( has_term( $categories_2, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        $string = 'another-class';
    }

    return $string;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_item_class', 10, 3 );
```

---

**OR** to add the term slugs as CSS class(es) instead, so you don't have to specify it via an if condition:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_item_class( $string, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    // Get the product categories slugs for this item
    $term_slugs = wp_get_post_terms( $cart_item['product_id'], 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) );

    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty ( $term_slugs ) ) {
        $string = implode( ' ', $term_slugs );
    }

    return $string;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_item_class', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Both works, Woocommerce adds product cats as css classes other places, so I've used this in archive and loops. 

But the way you suggest where I can define my own class is also good. Thanks for both suggestions.

Comment: For your 2nd code snippet, there is an issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77472180/3730754 answer that solve it.