# Add category class to WooCommerce cart product items & error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks, cart

In WooCommerce I am trying to apply product categories as a class to items in my cart. This is doing just that, BUT it then interferes with the ability to amend the cart values - the "Update Cart" button stops working. Removing this means that the update button works again.

```
function filter_woocommerce_cart_item_class( $string, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
// Get the product categories slugs for this item
$term_slugs = wp_get_post_terms( $cart_item['product_id'], 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) );

// NOT empty
if ( ! empty ( $term_slugs ) ) {
    $string = implode( ' ', $term_slugs );
}

return $string;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_item_class', 10, 3 );
```

Any advise on how to mitigate the problem appreciated.

Using answer from [Add CSS class(es) to WooCommerce cart items with (or based on) product categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72185196/add-css-classes-to-woocommerce-cart-items-with-or-based-on-product-categorie) - I would have commented on the post directly but my reputation is not over 50.

Answer (score 3):

You are most likely *removing* an already set class here, that is used to select the elements to bind the add-to-cart functionality to on the client side, by returning your own new classes only.

Don't overwrite `$string`, which already contains the classes the element should get before your modifications - append to it instead.

```
if ( ! empty ( $term_slugs ) ) {
    $string .= ' ' . implode( ' ', $term_slugs );
}
```

Comment: This solves the issue and work.

Comment: Perfect. The "Update Cart" button is now working as it should.